# Complex function and derivative

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, analysis, derivatives

Let $f$ be a holomorphic function and $u(x,y):= Re(f(z))$. Now I found a couple of times the expression $\partial_x u(x,y) -i \partial_y u(x,y).$ I guess this expression must be somehow related to the derivative of $f$. Is there any other interpretation of this expression?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\partial_x u(x,y) -i \partial_y u(x,y)\stackrel {Cauchy-Riemann}{=}\partial_x u(x,y) +i \partial_x v(x,y)=\partial_x f(z)=f'(z)$ .